# A combinatorics problem from from Baltic way math competition (1995)

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

This is a question from Baltic way math competition (1995).

> > A polygon with $2n + 1$ vertices is given. Show that it is possible to label the vertices and midpoints of the
> >     sides of the polygon, using all the numbers $1, 2, \dots , 4n + 2$, so that the sums of the three numbers assigned
> >     to each side are all equal.

The official solution is

First, label the midpoints of the sides of the polygon with the numbers $1, 2, \dots , 2n + 1$, in
clockwise order. Then, beginning with the vertex between the sides labelled by $1$ and $2$, label every second
vertex in clockwise order with the numbers $4n + 2, 4n + 1, \dots, 2n + 2$.

**My Question**
Is there any way by which this solution can be discovered in exam setup? I want to understand how this kind of problems can be systematically attacked.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let the vertex labels in clockwise order be $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ and the label of the edge between $i$ and $i+1$ be $b_i$. From the given condition, you can get: we get:
$a_{i+2}-a_i=b_{i}-b_{i+1}$ for all $i$, which suggests making this quantity  a constant such as 1.

Comment: A general principle is to look at a case which is manageable by computation. In this case looking at $n=1$ helps to understand the general case.

Answer (score 1):

"I want to understand how this kind of problem can be systematically attacked" - the classic work on systematic problem solving in mathematics is George Polya's *How To Solve It* - [here is a summary](http://math.berkeley.edu/~gmelvin/polya.pdf).

Comment: Maybe I've got the wrong impression, but this feels kind of like recommending a calculus text when someone asks how to evaluate a specific integral. Yeah, it's relevant and the answer's in there somewhere, but I would hope something more directly relevant can be said...

Answer (score 1):

I have done a lot of math contests in the past (some with success and others not so much) and when I first read this questions, the first thing that comes to mind is symmetry. Since each edge is isomorphic to any other edge, the edges should be treated in a "symmetric" way. So the thought would be to take either midpoints or vertices and treat them in a similar way (label with largest numbers, smallest numbers, or whatever else you can think of) and then try to treat vertices in a different but also symmetric way. Rotational assignments like this aren't uncommon with geometry/combinatorics problems.

This approach applies to most types of problems you see in math competitions, or at least it is a good place to start. Asking yourself "are any aspects of this problem symmetric?" often gives you a better understanding of the problem and sometimes gives you critical information.